# While installing instantclient_12_1 in Windows 10 it shows the following error

Tags: windows, odbc, jdbc-odbc, instantclient

While installing instantclient_12_1 in Windows 10 it shows the following error.

I will provide the Image of the error after we select the from instantclient_12_1 from Data Source (ODBC)[image]

it was the first error with follwing with next error in next pic
[image]
it was the NEXT error

Comment: Try running `\Windows\SYSWOW64\odbcad32.exe` to open the 32-bit ODBC Administrator and see if you get the same error messages there.

Comment: s same error came there also

Answer (score 0):

Download vcredist_x86 From the following [link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/B/C/5BC5DBB3-652D-4DCE-B14A-475AB85EEF6E/vcredist_x86.exe)

Then do the same Connectivity with 32 bit Software of `instantclient_12_1` from [oracle site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) and the dll(Instant Client Packages ODBC (32 bit)) files from the same link

For More Information Read this :- https://community.oracle.com/thread/3938283